# How can i change icons in QTreeView widget

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qt5

How can i change these icons? I can't find prop that change it in treeView settings.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [QTreeView::drawBranches](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#drawBranches) function in Qt. With this function you can draw the arbitrary icons at the left side of tree items, using the specified `QPainter`:

```cpp
void QTreeView::drawBranches(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect,
                             const QModelIndex &index) const
```

Another option is customize style sheets as it described in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview). Using these stylesheets, you can easily add the desired images as icons.

The above documentation link provides an example of such customization:

```css
QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:!adjoins-item {
    border-image: url(vline.png) 0;
}

QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:adjoins-item {
    border-image: url(branch-more.png) 0;
}

QTreeView::branch:!has-children:!has-siblings:adjoins-item {
    border-image: url(branch-end.png) 0;
}

QTreeView::branch:has-children:!has-siblings:closed,
QTreeView::branch:closed:has-children:has-siblings {
        border-image: none;
        image: url(branch-closed.png);
}

QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:!has-siblings,
QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:has-siblings  {
        border-image: none;
        image: url(branch-open.png);
}
```

As a result, they get the following result:

[image]